# What is the difference between normal relative clauses and the ones with という added?

Tags: grammar

Let's compare these 2 sentences

1. 私が来た意味
2. 私が来た**という**意味

I think both mean the same, but my intuition (although it may be wrong) tells me that 私が来た意味 more leans to the meaning of **The reason why i came**, while the latter more leans to **It means "i came"** as in explaining what does 私が来た mean. 
But i feel like both can mean the same in certain context.

Am i wrong? 
If yes, is there any difference, not only for the sentences above, but just in general?  
If there is, what causes it?

Comment: 意味 is *meaning* although *reason* could work in some contexts. 私が来た理由 is fine but 私が来たという理由 does not work.

Comment: Yeah im aware of that 私が来たという理由 doesnt work, but im not really sure why.. Im really not sure how という can affect the sentence, when even without it, the relative clause is already complete

Comment: You’re right. (This is too short for an answer

Comment: The comparison might become more interesting with こと, like 私が来たこと and 私が来たということ.

Comment: Are there any differences between those 2?  私が来たこと and 私が来たということ